# How to get the state of the mouse through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, mouseevent

I want to get whether the current mouse is pressed, such as the right button.

I know that you can use **mousedown** to maintain a variable to determine whether it has been pressed.

**But when mouseup on a disabled element**, there is no way to set state to up, which leads to subsequent state errors.

Is there an api to help me get the current mouse state?

example

```html
  <button disabled>disabled</button>
```

```js
    let state = 'up'
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      state = 'down'
      console.log('mouseDown')
    })
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      state = 'up'
      console.log('mouseup')
    })
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
      console.log('mousemove',state)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the the HTML Spec
A form control that is disabled must prevent any click events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.

So you can hack the behaviour using Capturing pointer events
give your button an id ex: "mybutton"

```
button=document.getElementById('mybutton')
button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
console.log('click')
})


button.addEventListener('pointerdown', event => {
    console.log('down')

});

button.addEventListener('pointerup', event => {
  console.log('up')
});
```

OR remove the disabled attribute and use css `pointer-events: none` this will prevent the button from responding and also you will still be able to get the mouse events